# Set Data Limit in Loggly

Tags: loggly

Is there any way to set limit in Loggly to take only last seven days logs information, other must be automatically deleted and than Loggly not be full because it will take only few days information.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a free account, Loggly will automatically delete the data after 7 days. You should not worry about how much data is in storage, so long as your volume is under 200 MB per day. This is measured from 00:00h UTC.